# Unix Joe Editor Default Settings

Tags: unix

Using JOE Text Editor I feel rather annoyed having to change the Word Wrap settings everytime I edit a document. I am sure there must be a way to define a set of defaults for the whole system once and for all. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

joe looks for its configuration in two places:

```
- /etc/joe/joerc
- $HOME/.joerc
```

There are also variants of these files references when the editor is invokved as jpico, jmacs, etc.

Either edit the global file or copy it to the proper place in your home directory and make sure that you have a line reading "-wordwrap" (presuming you want to enable it) starting in the first column.

You can also override the global settings on a per-file extension basis.

This is valid for joe v3.7; there may be subtle differences if you are running an older version but the specifics for your version should be in the manpage if they differ.

Comment: This is consistent with most programs on *nix.

Comment: Ya' beat me to it, James. Nice to see that other people use JOE. I've been accused of not being a hard-core *nix user because I don't use emacs (or, ugh, vi), but I do so love the Wordstar key sequences that I've grown accustomed to over the years, and JOE fills that niche well.

Comment: Thnx! Worked like charm!